# Time.parse "11-21-2017 3:00PM -0500" doesn't work - Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, time

I'm trying to parse a string into a Time/DateTime object.  This usually is pretty robust, but the particular format I'm working with is running into problems.  I have the string `"11-21-2017 3:00PM -0500"` and when running `Time.parse` I get and `argument out of range` error.  If I try to use something like `.to_datetime`, I get an error `invalid date`.

Is there something specifically wrong with my format, or is there something else going on here?

Comment: I don't think your format is completely worng. This works for me:

[4] pry(main)> Time.new '11-21-2017 3:00PM -0500'
=> 0011-01-01 00:00:00 +0230

Comment: It can be something specifically to your version of ror maybe

Comment: month-day-year is pretty unusual...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can reproduce your out of range issue.

You need to provide format of your date string.

Following code works:

```
DateTime.strptime("11-21-2017 3:00PM -0500", "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M%p %z")
```

Comment: Interestingly, this only works with the format `3:00PM`.  If you use `3:00 PM` it will cause an invalid date error.

Answer (score 2):

Time.parse failing to identify format of time you are providing, better you should go ahead with using

```
   Time.strptime("11-21-2017 3:00PM -0500", "%m-%d-%Y %I:%M%p %z")
```

This accepts both time and format as arguments.  For API documentation refer the link https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/time/rdoc/Time.html#method-c-strptime

I hope this helps you.